# Selection of covariance structures in SAS PROC GLIMMIX

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, aic, covariance-matrix

Stroup and Claassen (2020) recently published an article titled Pseudo-Likelihood or Quadrature? What We Thought We Knew, What We Think We Know, and What We Are Still Trying to Figure Out in the Journal of Agricultural, Biological and Environmental Statistics [<doi.org/10.1007/s13253-020-00402-6](https://doi.org/10.1007/s13253-020-00402-6)>  (paywall, unless you are an ASA member).  In the article, they give some very solid reasoning for using the default RSPL method for GLIMMIX for a variety of distributions.  Now comes the problem - RSPL does not allow for the calculation of information criteria, as the linearization leads to different pseudo-data for various covariance structures.

My question is this - would it make sense to use Gaussian quadrature or Laplace method to select a covariance structure based on (for instance) AICC, and then switch to RSPL for a final analysis?

Comment: What is their reasoning ?

Comment: From the conclusions section (key lines):   Quadrature’s downward-biased variance MLEs result in inflated type I error rates and poor coverage in designs with minimal replication, but improve—provided the analysis GLMM is consistent with the data-generating process—when replication is increased relative to the number of treatments.  AND ALSO: Suffice it to say, however, that if a procedure cannot control type I error, as is so often the case with quadrature estimation, it should not be used.  SO This would be an excellent read for anyone working in this area.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out !

Comment: (+1) Hopefully Dimitris Rizopoulos or Ben Bolker will see this.